# How to pass in state as a prop for reactnative component? (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have components that have redundant code. I want to create a reusable component that will accept the property of a state that I want to update as a prop. How could I do so?

```
<Text> Calories</Text>
<TextInput
 style={styles.input}
 onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, calories: parseInt(event) }))}
 keyboardType={'numeric'}
 value={item.calories}
/>
                    
<Text> Protein</Text>
<TextInput
 style={styles.input}
 onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, protein: parseInt(event) }))}
 keyboardType={'numeric'}
 value={item.protein}
/>
```

Tried doing something like this with template literals but it doesnt work

```
export const Test = ({value}) => {
    return (<>

        <Text> {value}</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => (`{ ...prevState, $(value): parseInt(event) }`))}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            value={`item.${value}`}
        />
    </>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the states you passed into the component is not enough, you need to share the **display value** and the **function for modifing parent component states**.

You can create your custom component like this.

```
export default Test = ({title, value, onChangeText}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Text> {title}</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                keyboardType={'numeric'}
                value={value}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

In you parent component, import your custom component and pass props to it.

```
import Test from '../{path_to_the_component}'

<Test
    title={"Calories"}
    value={item.calories}
    onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, calories: parseInt(event) }))}
/>

<Test
    title={"Protein"}
    value={item.protein}
    onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, protein: parseInt(event) }))}
/>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. that works, but i have almost the same amount of code/redundancy since I have to pass in so many props so ill probably wont change anything to maintain readability

Answer (score 0):

Your literal strings approach had the fundamentals. Just the strings did not work.

```js
const Test = ({ value, item, setItem }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text> {value}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(event) =>
          setItem((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [value]: parseInt(event) }))
        }
        keyboardType={"numeric"}
        value={item[value]}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

And then you can use it like

```js
<Test
  value={'protein'}
  setItem={setItem}
  item={item}
/>
```

Comment: tried implementing this, but I cant input anything inside textinput as the value is not changing.

Comment: i tried passing my values such as protein and calories as a string, so maybe its not working `<Test value={'calorie'}/>`

Comment: @benwl I updated my answer, I forgot to mention that the test also needs access to the `item` and `setItem`

Comment: so it still doesnt work, and i think its because when i try to change the input, as soon as i enter one character, the `item` state gets updated, and my `Test` component refreshes. as a result, I cant properly enter anything in the textinput.

Comment: Im thinking i can have an internal useState hook for `Test` and implement the onSubmitEditing prop.  lmk if you have a better suggestion though :)

Comment: I created this [live preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hugle-czdglz) and it works just fine!